# Any 'pretty' data visualization libraries for Python?

Tags: python, graphics, data-visualization

There are plenty of 'pretty-printing' visualization libraries for Javascript. E.g. those listed [here.](http://datavisualization.ch/tools/13-javascript-libraries-for-visualizations)

Googling for 'python visualization libraries' only turns up stuff like VTK and mayavi, which are primarily more for no-nonsense scientific use.

So, do you know of any Python libraries similar to those Javascript ones in the above link? I particularly like the [Javascript Infovis Toolkit.](http://thejit.org/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Python there really isn't "one viz library to rule them all". There are different libraries and toolkits for different purposes. For graphs in Python you may find [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) useful. For other types of scientific or data visualizations [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is also good.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a new port of R's **ggplot2** over to python. Looks very slick!

https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/

More info here:
http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/ggplot-for-python.html

---

Also have a look at **Seaborn**, described as "Improved matplotlib for statistical data visualization":
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn

The Seaborn examples are pretty slick:

[Plotting Complex Linear Models](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/master/examples/linear_models.ipynb)

[Visualization Distributions](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/master/examples/plotting_distributions.ipynb)

[Time Series Visualizations](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/master/examples/timeseries_plots.ipynb)

Answer (score 5):

[Check out Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) at [pydata](http://pydata.org/)

source code [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh)

Answer (score 2):

There's [PyCha](http://bitbucket.org/lgs/pycha/wiki/Home) for charts.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for graph software?

Checkout http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php. it has python bindings.

Answer (score 1):

I second matplotlib. Also Chaco.  It's not Python, but for really quick heatmaps, go to OpenHeatMap.com

Answer (score 0):

[Networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) looks to be the best-documented of the graph libraries I've seen. I think it interfaces with Matplotlib for visualization.

Comment: Networkx is absolutely awesome. You can produce some nice looking stuff with it via Matplotlib or you can use [Pygraphviz](http://pygraphviz.github.io/) to have it talk to Graphviz.