# Results not appearing neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I have only about 16000 nodes in my database and when I do match n return n I never get any graph back, any reason why or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Either you have no relation between the nodes - when using the browser GUI check the result as table.
You can limit this for testing e.g. match (n) return n limit 25.

Comment: I do have relations between nodes.  I can do limit 500 and that works but when I try and get all the graph never comes back

Comment: You will find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031795/resultset-too-large-over-1000-rows-in-neo4j-browser.